# Connecting for the first time - reconnect

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

Currently this is not supported in paho java library, but I need this functionality in our application. For example, on application startup, we didn't have network connection, but after 30 seconds or so, we established connection successfully so I want my client to connect automatically.

My question is - what would be best approach to accomplish this? What I tried so far is to try to reconnect if something goes wrong during connect method. And since we use RxJava I have scheduled execution of the same method which is responsible for client connection. It will be easier if I paste the code.

```
private void connect(String brokerUrl) {
try {

    LOG.info("Connecting to the broker...");
    mqttClient.connect(connectionOptions, "Connecting", new IMqttActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
            LOG.info("Successfully conected to the broker.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            LOG.error("Failed to connect to broker. Trying to reconnect in {} milliseconds...", connectionRetryTimeout, exception);
            // try to reconnect in few seconds
            Schedulers.io().scheduleDirect(() -> connect(brokerUrl), connectionRetryTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    });

} catch (MqttException e) {
    LOG.error("Connection error.", e);
}
}
```

What happens like this is that, when network connection is available I manage to connect automatically, but second thread is created which continues to retry to connect to broker. Does anyone already implemented this, or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be implementing a callback (asynchronous event based) that informs you as soon as teh network is available again

```
interface INetworkCallback{

    void onNetworkStateChange(boolean newState);

}
```

and somewhere implement the interface

Comment: Well, network connection unavailable at first connect is just one possible case when something goes wrong. It can happened that broker is down when we try to connect.